# Making file upload action add unique suffix to filename as it is saved on server using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, upload

I have searched around but found mainly PHP-related answers which are not suitable for me this time.

**Background**
I have successfully got a webform working on my IIS server using some C# ASP.NET.

It allows up to three files to be uploaded to the server simultaneously. What I'd like is for the code to add the immediate date/time to the end of the filename (before the extension) so that there is no chance of a file being overwritten with the same name and ensures every file uploaded has a unique filename.

**Why? How is this happening anyway?**
If I choose to upload a photo from my iOS device using Safari it renames the photo file "image.jpg". It means I cannot effectively upload multiple files from the iOS device simultaneously because it leaves me with one photo uploaded to the server called "image.jpg".

**My code so far**

```html
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   string filepath = "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\upload\\files";
   HttpFileCollection uploadedFiles = Request.Files;
    
   for (int i = 0; i < uploadedFiles.Count; i++)
   {    
      HttpPostedFile userPostedFile = uploadedFiles[i];
    
      try
      {    
         if (userPostedFile.ContentLength > 0 )
         {
            Label1.Text += "<u>File #" + (i+1) + 
               "</u><br>";
            Label1.Text += "File Content Type: " + 
               userPostedFile.ContentType + "<br>";
            Label1.Text += "File Size: " + 
               userPostedFile.ContentLength + "kb<br>";
            Label1.Text += "File Name: " + 
               userPostedFile.FileName + "<br>";
    
            userPostedFile.SaveAs(filepath + "\\" + 
               System.IO.Path.GetFileName(userPostedFile.FileName));
    
            Label1.Text += "Location where saved: " + 
               filepath + "\\" + 
               System.IO.Path.GetFileName(userPostedFile.FileName) + 
               "<p>";
         }    
      } 
      catch (Exception Ex)
      {    
         Label1.Text += "Error: <br>" + Ex.Message;    
      }    
   }    
 }
```

**Example I'd like to see after solution**
Files should be placed in the upload directory like
*_173613082015.jpg *(right now it is 17:36 on 13th Aug 2015)*
where the * represents the original filename given by the client (however, just to be clear, the file extension doesn't have to be jpg, could be png, docx, xlsx and so on depending on what the client is uploading).

Thank you for reading and hoping this can be useful to anyone else!

Comment: fyi, it's easier to add a filename prefix than suffix (as you don't have to split the file and extension) - additionally your prefix as a timestamp would always be the same number of characters, so it's much easier to "line up" when parsing a directory visually for a specific timestamped file as the timestamp is easy to pick out at the beginning of a string.  That's my opinion anyway :O

Answer (score 1):

I would think you could just do something like this:

```
string fullFile = filepath + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss_") +
           System.IO.Path.GetFileName(userPostedFile.FileName);

userPostedFile.SaveAs(fullFile);

Label1.Text += "Location where saved: " + 
           fullFile +
           "<p>";
```

Files would look like:

```
20150813125700_MyFile.txt
```

The reason i suggest prepending vs appending is consider the two lists:

```
LongFileNameThatsReallyLongLikeTotally.txt
Short.txt
MediumFileNameLengthBlah.txt
a.txt
ThisFilenameisgonnabeweirdorsomething.txt
```

appending the timestamp:

```
LongFileNameThatsReallyLongLikeTotally_20150813125700.txt
Short_20150813125700.txt
MediumFileNameLengthBlah_20150813125700.txt
a_20150813125700.txt
ThisFilenameisgonnabeweirdorsomething_20150813125700.txt
```

prepending the timestamp:

```
20150813125700_LongFileNameThatsReallyLongLikeTotally.txt
20150813125700_Short.txt
20150813125700_MediumFileNameLengthBlah.txt
20150813125700_a.txt
20150813125700_ThisFilenameisgonnabeweirdorsomething.txt
```

See how in the "append" scenario your eye has to scan different horizontal parts to read the timestamp, whereas in the "prepend" scenario that is not the case.

Honestly though, if you're worried about overlapping filenames you might be better off using a GUID.  Imagine if your user selected "image.jpg" from 3 separate folders for upload in a single submit.  What would happen then?

If you add a `Guid.NewGuid()` to each file, you'll have no overlap (but lose out on having a nice timestamp in the filename).

Comment: Great, thank you Kritner.
Where exactly does your suggested code go? It duplicates the file upload now - one with and one without the date/time prefix.

Comment: It would be placed in the same place of your current save as logic... you don't need both

Comment: Thank you, that now works. There is still the problem where iOS device sends photo files as 20150813125700_image.jpg for all uploaded files and therefore only the last file is saved (the other three files are overwritten because they all share the same file name).

Perhaps if the date added also included some kind of count or milliseconds, in an effort to make each filename unique to the destination directory on the server?